# Is it possible to overwrite the Standard Variant in SmartVariantManagement?

Tags: odata, sapui5, variant

I created a smart table using the columns provided by OData service and the corresponding metadata. I also added the smart variant management to the smart table by setting the properties `useVariantManagement`, `useTablePersonalisation` and `persistencyKey`. I can now see the variant management control and create new variants. So far so good.

However, since there is no way to define the column width in the annotation file for the OData service (or is there?), the columns have a predefined width in the standard variant. Therefore, I am resizing the column widths in the afterRendering event of the smart table to consider the length of the data provided by the OData service. The problem I now face is that by resizing the columns, I am adjusting the standard variant and am therefore getting a modified flag (so it says `Standard*`).

I can see that it is not possible to adjust or delete the standard variant in the frontend but is there any way to save the new layout as the standard variant in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite column widths client side in the XML:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable entitySet="Setname" ...>
    <t:Table alternateRowColors="true" visibleRowCountMode="Auto" selectionMode="MultiToggle">
        <t:columns>
            <t:Column width="5em" sortProperty="Columnname" filterProperty="Columnname" app:p13nData='\{"columnKey": "Columnname", "leadingProperty": "Columnname"}'>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{Columnname}"/>
                </t:template>
                <Label text="{/#Setname/Columnname/@sap:label}"/>
            </t:Column>
            ...
```

Comment: I know that I can set the column widths in the XML file. However, I use OData annotations to define the columns of the table because I have quite a few columns and annotations and want to keep the maintenance to a minimum. Therefore, I was wondering if there was a way to set the width in the OData annotations because I have not found any up to this point. But thank you for your fast response!

Comment: No this is not possible (as far as I know) via annotations, that's why I also have to do this frequently.

Comment: @luuksen What can't be done via annotation (mostly UI related issues) sometimes can be done via UI asaptation. Through SAPUI5 visual editor you can set the width of your columns (in a static way). Hope this helps!